# UITableViewCell with two UIStackViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistackview

I'm facing a layout issue with a UITableViewCell which consists (from top to bottom) of (1)a UIStackView, (2)a UIView with a fixed height and (3)another UIStackView. In the top UIStackView I want to place a few instances of UILabel vertically, depending on some datastructure. These labels can vary in height. In the bottom UIStackView I want to place a few instances of UIButton vertically. This number also depends on some data structure.

The problem has to do with AutoLayout (at least I think it does). How would I set up the constraints in such a way, that the UITableViewCell creates both enough space for the top UIStackView and the bottom UIStackView when it needs to be placed on screen. The layout of the cell is defined in a separate XIB file.

So far I have a heightconstraint on the top UIStackView. Depending on the frameheight of the labels the height of the stackview is adjusted. But it turns out, that the height always has the same value. I know this, because I need two instances of this particular UITableViewCell in my TableView.
The bottom UIStackView does NOT have a heightconstraint and has always a correct layout.

Do I need to adjust the properties for vertical hugging/compression resistance priority?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood your issue, but why are you fixing the height of the top StackView if it's height is supposed to be dynamic ? You should remove this constraint and set intrinsic sizes (below "Content compression resistance priority") of both StackView to "placeholder" to keep IB happy. 
The top StackView will then behave the same as the bottom one, provided you don't have other constraints issues.

Comment: You did not misunderstood. I added the heightconstraint to keep IB happy. After the removal of this constraint and setting the Intrinsic Size to 'Placeholder' for only the top StackView, it all seems to work  just fine. Saved my day, many thanks!